# WordPress Code Organization

Tags: wordpress, code-organization

I'm working on a premium theme for WordPress, it's my first. My question is how modular should/can I get my code before it gets to be a problem for the server or other developers who buy my theme?

For example I have 3 custom post types with taxonomies and custom column headings. Should they all be in one php file or can I break them up so that each post type is in its own file?

I'm thinking that for future projects more modular is the way to go so I can just drag and drop the pieces that I need for that project. I don't want to make my theme any slower though so I could use a little advise on how granular to make my files.

I've bought themes in the past that have both extremes but want to set myself up properly from the start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an opinion request this one because either approach works and based on this information plus the fact you seem keen on individual files. I would encourage just that.

Modular approach works with themes if you plan to provide the same functionality per theme as you won't need to edit functions per theme. I would go with individual files and just put them in a folder. If one of those files has a bug you'll be quick on applying the changes to all the themes you create.

If you put all the functions in one file and each theme gets its own versions of those files due to requests etc. Then you create a little more work in that you copy and paste code. Not a lot of work but then that demands on just how much that single file changes over the years or even within some months.

There is nothing wrong with many folders and files. It won't have an effect on loading. It would take hundreds of include() or require() before it becomes an issue.

Comment: Thanks. That's the direction I was thinking but thought it would be foolish to not throw the question out there in case there was something I was unaware of.